# Using Blazor virtualize for a two-column container

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a Blazor WASM application and I want to use Virtualize to display a list of employee cards. The application design includes displaying employee cards in two columns. The following code is responsible for rendering the page with the list of user cards:

```
<div style="height: 500px; overflow-y:scroll; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;">
    <Virtualize Items="@employees">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="@context.Image" />
            <div class="name">@context.Name />
        </div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>
```

When scrolling the page, the next group of items is not loading. If I leave only one column by changing `grid-template-columns: 1fr;`, the scrolling works correctly.

I was expecting there to be some configuration in the Virtualize component to display the content in multiple columns, but I couldn't find anything suitable.